# Should my custom class be set as my referencing outlet?

Tags: cocoa

I'm sure this has been asked before in a better way, but I'm trying to understand how interface elements relate to classes. My application is very simple, mainly an `NSTextView` that gets populated with some output logs.

I've been just using `AppDelegate` to handle most of my app's function, but now I want to break things up a little. So I have created a `Logger` class that has all the code relating to the logging part, including handling updating the NSTextView. So what I'm not sure about is should I hook the NSTextView's referencing outlet directly to the Logger class, or should I keep these two things decoupled and just pass a reference of the NSTextView to the Logger object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Logger`, on top of it's logging logic, sounds like it also contains presentation logic-- which just takes your model (data), formats it, then directly passes it to your `NSTextView` to display it.

It sounds like your `NSTextView` is inherently connected to your `Logger`.  If you connect your `NSTextView` to an outlet in your `Logger`, you will be able to easily set the `stringValue` of the `NSTextView` through that reference.

Also, as you said the alternative would be to have another object obtain a reference to your `NSTextView`, then pass it to your `Logger`.  Because your `Logger` controls the presentation of your `NSTextView`, that wouldn't be necessary.  In fact, it should be the other way around-- you can make your `IBOutlet` public (by placing it in your header file, instead of in the class extension in the implementation file), if any other objects need a reference to your `NSTextView` (Like a window that wants a reference to that view to display)

So I believe you do in fact want to connect the two